# Проверять человека в канале

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-3.7

Я делаю бота на *python* `pytelegrambotapi`

Я хотел бы, чтобы мой бот проверял человека, который написал старт боту,есть ли он в канале или нет.

Если нету, то тогда бот не должен работать пока юзер не присоединится.

Comment: прикрепите ваш код

Comment: пусть пишет не в личку а в канале

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать запрос `getChatMember` по *user_id* и *chat_id* (канал) и смотреть на `status` в результате

Доки [тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember)

В pytelegrambotapi:

```py
bot.get_chat_member(user_id, chat_id)
```

Comment: можно подробнее????
@ivart
жду